# php mail function with attachments

Tags: php, email-attachments

I'm trying to make a form that sends me a mail.

This is the html file content.

```
<form method="post" action="email.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" id="contact_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="user_name"/>
<input type="text" id="contact_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address"     
name="user_mail" <textarea id="contact_message" class="form-control" rows="7" placeholder="Write a 
message" name="user_message"></textarea>
<input name="attachment" type="file">      
<input type="submit" value="Send mail" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"/>
 </form>
```

and this is the php file.

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
 if(!empty($_FILES['attachment']['name'])) {
   $file_name = $FILES['attachment']['name'];  
   $temp_name = $FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];  
   $file_type = $FILES['attachment']['type'];

   $base = basename($file_name);
   $extension = substr($base, strlen($base)-4, strlen($base));

   //only these file types will be allowed
   $allowed_extensions = array(".doc", "docx", ".pdf", ".zip", ".png");

   //check that this file type is allowed
   if(in_array($extension,$allowed_extensions)) {
       //mail essentials
       $from = $_POST['user_mail'];
       $to = "eugenepi1025@gmail.com";
       $subject = $_POST['user_name'];
       $message = $_POST['user_message'];

       //things u need
       $file = $temp_name;
       $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
       $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));  //unique identifier

       //standard mail headers
       $header = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
       $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto. "\r\n";
       $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";


       //declare multiple kinds of email (plain text + attch)
       $header .="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
       $header .="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";

       //plain txt part

       $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
       $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
       $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
       $header .= $message. "\r\n\r\n";


       //attch part
       $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
       $header .= "Content-Type: ".$file_type."; name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
       $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
       $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n\r\n";
       $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";  //chucked up 64 encoded attch


       //sending the mail - message is not here, but in the header in a multi part

       if(mail($to, $subject, "", $header)) {
       echo "success";
       }else {
           echo "fail";
       }


   }else {
       echo "file type not allowed"; }    //echo an html file
}else {
  echo "no file posted"; }    
}
?>
```

The thing is that `file type not allowed` message keeps coming. But I uploaded a .png file, so I don't know what is the problem.

Could you please help me with this? I've been hanging on to this for hours :(

Comment: You're missing the _close-delimiter_. Add `$header .= "--$uid--\r\n";` at the end.

Answer (score 5):

actualy you have

```
$file_name = $FILES['attachment']['name'];  
$temp_name = $FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];  
$file_type = $FILES['attachment']['type'];
```

it should be

```
$file_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];  
$temp_name = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];  
$file_type = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];
```

and it works perfectly :))

Comment: gosh, why i did not notice that ;( thanks so much for your help

Comment: I can't see a difference between the two code blocks except a `\`` character, probably a typo. Can you please provide a solution? Also, this provides a MIME type information about the file, but the OP checks for extensions.

Comment: $FILES AND $_FILES are very different variables. And he usesing $FILES which is not existing variable.. and useless :) he just forgot the underscore "_" .. and sorry for the bracket.. :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, i didn't catch that either. Thank you for the explanation :)

Comment: no problem :) user2106381 also didn't saw his problem :)

Comment: hmm... glad to know that things work out :) but it's a 'she', not 'he' hehe :)

Comment: well sorry :) from your username it's hard to tell :)

Answer (score 3):

Also, make sure your header `Content-Type` for your image attachment is assigned the correct MIME type i.e. `image/png` for `.png` file. Refers this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_image) for a list of image MIME types.

Comment: wow, new information. thanks, i've just checked that wiki page :) it's nice to learn new things. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You're exceeding the string size in `substr()`, so your `$extension` isn't correct.

For `a.pdf`; `strlen($base)` is 5; so the ending index is 4. Therefore, your third parameter should be `strlen($base) - 1` instead of `strlen($base)`.

Change the line as follows:

```
$extension = substr($base, strlen($base) - 4, strlen($base) - 1);
```

I think this approach is even better :

```
$extension = substr($base, strrpos($base, ".")-1);
```

Which would give you the last `.` character and the rest of the string, a.k.a. the file extension.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/SNXtdS).